# How to setup multiple domains in IIS 7.5

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, domain

I have the following domains:

1. site1.com
2. site2.com
3. etc.
4. site10.com

I have been able to setup site1.com to point to my server and can access it with Remote Desktop.  I want to add all of the other sites to access the same server.

I have already setup DNS records with CPanel and Domain Aliases.  All of the name server records for these domains point to the NS of site1.com.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are asking?

If you are asking in a Windows Server 2008 R2 server can join multiple Windows domains, then no.

If you want to have multiple websites on the same server, with different domains, all going to the same address, then this is done by having the DNS for the domains resolve to the same IP address.

Comment: please read all text in my above post. i explained my problem. i want connect multiple domains to one site in a web server (windows 2008 r2)

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache? Iis?

Comment: my web server is iis 7.5

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are asking a couple of questions which is typically not recommended.  If you have multiple questions split them out into multiple questions.

There are two things you have to modify to get multiple domain names to point to a single site/IP on your web server.

1. Update host headers in IIS
2. Update your DNS records to point to your server's IP

#### Host Headers

Check out the [IIS site](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/762/create-a-web-site/) to learn how to setup a web site.  You can follow the instructions to setup host headers for each of your domains site2.com, etc.

#### Update your DNS Records

For each domain you should be able to specify an A record that then points to the IP address of your server.  Once completed it should then browse to the same site as site1.com.